# Como almacenar el token de una respuesta al hacer POST en swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy haciendo un login en una app desde una API con el metodo POST, al hacer el login, me devuelve un token y este lo tengo que usar para hacer otras peticiones dentro de la App,
Como y donde podría almacenar el token?

```
func getTournamentLis(){
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {return}
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ [self] data,response,error in
            if let response = response{
                print("Este es el response \(response)")
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do{
                let datos = try JSONDecoder().decode([GetTournamentModel].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataTournament = datos
                    print("Se obtuvo correctamente \(datos)")
                }
            }catch let error as NSError{
                print("Error al hacer POST", error.localizedDescription)
                }
            
        }.resume()
    }

func login(email: String, password: String){
        guard let url = URL(string: urlAUTH) else {return}
        let parametros = ["apiKey":apIKEY, "password":password, "user":email]
        let body = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parametros)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = body
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data,response,error in
            if let response = response{
                print("Este es el response \(response)")
            }
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do{
                let datos = try JSONDecoder().decode(PostModel.self, from: data)
                if !datos.token.isEmpty{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.usrToken = datos.token
                        self.authenticate = 1
                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: "session")
                    }
                }
            }catch let error as NSError{
                print("Error al hacer POST", error.localizedDescription)
                print(data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authenticate = 2
                    self.authenticate2 = true
                    
                }
                }
            
        }.resume()
    }
```

Si pongo el token manualmente, funciona todo correctamente, el detalles es obtenerlo despues de hacer el login

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y colocar ahí el nuevo código. En el nuevo código estás usando `UserDefaults` para la sesión; por qué no usas lo mismo para el token?

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias,  Ya entendí cómo hacerlo!!

Comment: Tokens deberian de mantenerse en un lugar seguro como [KeyChain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain) no en el lugar mas inseguro